# Putting down my mug

Tags: discussion, moderators

I joined CR in May 2013, but only started living here in September of that year. I remember very well then, the site had been in beta for almost 1000 days, and I kept thinking that was a shame, CR was such an awesome twist of the Stack Exchange format, it *had* to "graduate".

Soon I met folks that would become the "core" of the embryo of the rather healthy community CR was to become a few months later. I spent so much time in what was then known as *Code Review Chat* (or something boring like that), that the chat system eventually made me room owner, for the previous owner hadn't shown up in chat for well over half a year - soon that chatroom was to be renamed *The 2nd Monitor*, and the rest is History.

When I look back at that time - end of 2013, beginning of 2014, it feels like the bunch of us ended up reviving a ghost town. The whole story is in the now-frozen [CRonicles](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/27598/2015/8/31), if you're curious. Here's a chart from mid-2015 (thanks @rolfl!) depicting the Great Revival of CR - I have to say I'm extremely proud to have been a part of this:

[image: The 2014 Great Revival of Code Review]

Mid-2015 coincides with CR's long-awaited graduation. We had done it! Top users got CR swag, elections were held, a rubber ducky was sacrificed (can't find the link, but I'm sure @Pimgd knows what I'm talking about), and boom here we are all these years later, and I feel old and nostalgic now.

So yeah. I was elected by this awesome community in June 2015, and it feels like forever ago. When I signed the moderator agreement, I thought I was going for a year, and then pass the torch. Turns out, on Stack Exchange when you're elected as a moderator, you're up there until you step down (or do something very stupid). #Mod4Life!

So my time has come. Already last year I had recurring thoughts of stepping down, and ended up sticking around. Maybe I should have - my site and moderator activity this past year has been next to nothing, especially when I compare to the burning passion that got me there in the first place.

I've lost that flame now, so rather than keep a diamond I'm hardly using, I'm stepping down, hoping elections will be held to bring up the very best of Code Review folks. I'll definitely be keeping an eye on this!

Not sure when I'll be losing the diamond, but the Stack Exchange Community Team was made aware of my decision; the rest of the CR moderator team, too (although I haven't had a chance to chat directly with everyone).

This isn't the end of anything, I'm not disappearing: it's just me putting down my empty mug.

Thank you, Code Review!

Comment: If we downvote, does that mean you'll stay as a mod? :)

Comment: @SimonForsberg hahaha funny... nope - I had been thinking of stepping down for too long now, ...decision's made!

Comment: The sad story about the Duck can be found [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/27803097#27803097) and [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/28770559#28770559)

Comment: Thank you for your 2 years and 8 months of service. You've been a great mod, and it's sad to see you step down. All the best man.

Comment: You've done a lot as a diamond, but you've really done a lot just as a member of the community. I can't say I've learned as much from anyone as I have from you - but maybe that's just because of the languages I use.

Comment: I haven't been active for awhile now, but I can say you've always been a model here. I wish you great luck with your future projects :)

Comment: My rubber duckyyyyyy

Comment: thank you for your commitment and knowledge sharing

Answer (score 18):

#### It's been a pleasure!

I also remember the old days. I remember the mission and the zombies (heck, the zombies seem to never go away entirely...) You've been a good Mug, a good friend and a good moderator. I hope you will stay a good Mug and a good friend at least. It's sad to see you leave The 1st Monitor (yup, that's totally the name of our moderator chat room) but I totally understand and respect your decision.

Thank you for the good work you have done!

Answer (score 17):

I agree that it seems like it's been forever ago, and I'm so proud of what Code Review has become today. I want to personally thank you for all you have done, and no doubt will continue to do as a normal user, to make this site not only useful to many, but also welcoming and friendly!

## Cheers!

Answer (score 16):

It's sad to see you go, but I understand that you spent a lot of time coming to this decision and felt that it would be best for yourself and everyone.  It has been a pleasure working alongside you for these past few years.

Your vast contributions of data and ideas for helping to fight the "zombie apocalypse" shows what it means to use one's talents and dedication to truly benefit  your site, your fellow community members, and your fellow coders.  We'll never forget your lasting service to this site and the future of others.

We'll be sure to preserve your mug and all its coffee stains built up from hours spent doing what you do best (unless you still want it cleaned out anyway). :)

Thank you!

Answer (score 15):

I'm very sad that you leave, but I respect your decision. You've been a great mod, and I will miss you in The 1st Monitor. Hopefully not on the site just yet, and I guess I can always find you...If I participate more in [The 2nd](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor) ;-) My only regret is not being able to have a beer with you right now. I hope that day will come. Thank You!

Answer (score 14):

> Thank you, Code Review!

Thank you, Mug!

This site has a long and interesting [history](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/27598/2015/8/31) and you've been part of it in quite a significant manner for most of it. You've been active, participating, helpful and overall [positive](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/8595?m=17403862#17403862). Always spreading the faith, but in a more positive manner than many of us could muster (I learned a lot from you in that regard).

All good things come to an end. While I'm somewhat sad to see you go, I completely understand your reasoning. If the flame isn't there, pass the position to someone whose flame is still alive. Thank you for serving.

Comment: I *knew* there was a matching song for this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4pBo-GL9SRg

Answer (score 13):

Changes are as good as a vacation. You deserve a break, so take some time to enjoy it, and know that Code Review is a (much) better place because of your contributions. Also, Code Review will always be in good hands. I've learned that lesson myself, good people step up to take the reigns. Further, it's good to get fresh blood in to the leadership (also a lesson I learned).

Mat, it's been great being part of the story with you for so long! You were the first person to welcome me here, and that was the start of the good times for me on Code Review. Thanks!

> [*(21 Nov 2013)* `retailcoder`: @rolfl well hello!](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12277952#12277952)

Comment: Awww, [the nostalgia](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12241052#12241052)...

Answer (score 10):

I don't remember anything, really, but I always liked you, Mat. Even if we didn't always get along or agree - you were a good voice to hear and see in the community. You made the hard choices, you made the easy choices, but you never put anyone down for it. Respect, my friend.

Answer (score 9):

Thank you for explaining and showing to plenty of people (including me) that [vba](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vba) is a normal language (and not a "funny" scripting thing or the bastard of programming languages) and writing a good code does not depend on the language, but on the one's abilities to program.

Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

I know you aren't going anywhere, you are just not going to be a Mod, and I will miss you (*or not because you aren't going anywhere*) 
I had to say something so I could post this picture,  it came to mind when I read the title and it is funny on so many levels

[image: You aren't really putting the Mug down, I don't think you could if you wanted to...]